# Having line breaks between <li>s

Tags: html, newline, html-lists, line-breaks

I have a horizontal menu consisting of `<li>` elements with `display: inline`.

The elements are supposed to be next to each other seamlessly.

In the source code, I would like to have each li on one line for easier debugging:

```
<li class="item1 first"> ... </li>
<li class="item2"> ... </li>
...
```

However, if I add a `\n` after each element, the menu items have a gap between each other. I gather this is the intended behaviour, but is there any way to turn it off using a clever "white-space" setting or something?

> Edit: I can't use float, this is in a CMS with the option to center the list items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid the rendering issues but keep the code maintainable like this:

```
<ul
  ><li>item 1</li
  ><li>item 2</li
  ><li>item 3</li
></ul>
```

It removes the whitespace but it's still easy to edit the items in a text editor, provided your CMS doesn't mess with the markup you enter!

Comment: Hey, this is a great idea! I think I will use this.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing, John.  The new line character is treated as white space just like any other white space and most browsers convert those to a single blank space separating words or whatever elements.  If you put the new line inside the tag, the browser won't render it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the ability to edit the CSS? If so, you could try adjusting the padding/margins on the <li> element. It does seem to be a lot of effort of readability.

Depending on what browser you are using you can get the HTML Tidy http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/, which gives you the option to Tidy up your source, which might be useful enough for debugging

Comment: HTML Tidy is not an option because it is production code I am debugging. Still, good idea.

Answer (score 0):

CSS+float is your friend.

Comment: I can't use float, this is in a CMS with the option to center the list items

Answer (score 0):

HTML is whitespace independent - so adding line breaks should have no effect. Some browser's rendering engines don't quite get this right however.

What you probably want to do is add

`float: left;`

to your li tags to get them next to each other.

Comment: I can't use float, this is in a CMS with the option to center the list items.

Comment: Adam: of course whitespace is not ignored in `inline` mode. Otherwise there would be no spaces between the words in your sentences.